# Testing asynchronous API, with Given-When-Then style, multiple When-Then?

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, junit, assertj

I know it is recommended to have "single assert" in tests or single group of "When" and "Then" in BDD paradigm.

I was thinking whether it would be okay to relax this assumption, when testing an *asynchronous* API. Where request has to be first made, and then later it completes.

Something like this:

```
@Rule
public final Java6JUnitSoftAssertions softly = new Java6JUnitSoftAssertions();

@Test
public void setLessStrictCriterionGivenAllFetchesCompleted() {
    givenRepoWithCriterion(new MockCriterion(2));
    givenAllFetchesCompleted();

    // When I set a less strict criterion of ">= 1"
    final MockCriterion criterionMinValue1 = new MockCriterion(1);
    itemRepo.setCriteriaAndFetch(criterionMinValue1);

    // Then there is a fetch request in the queue, to fetch ">= 1"
    assertQueue(criterionMinValue1);
    // And there are loading items
    assertRepoItems(null, null, null);
    assertAll();

    // -------- Notice second group of When-Then starts here --------

    // When the fetch finishes
    fetcher.yieldFetch();

    // Then item list is 1 2 3
    assertRepoItems(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Note that there are *two* groups of When-Then.

The `assertAll()` is there to force asserting the first group of AssertJ soft assertions.

The fetches are normally done via HTTP in the real implementation, but, for the tests, there is a mocked fetcher and the finish of a fetch is emulated via `fetcher.yieldFetch();`

**Would you consider that overall structure to be a good way to write such tests?**

What other/better ways might be there?

Comment: Using mock objects to mimic user behaviour seems not very BDD. Is BDD really a 'thing' here or are you more concerned about high-level integration tests which depend on asynchronous behaviours?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The truth is, that I got a review, for a previous version, saying "use given/when/then" and "one assert per test". So I'm trying to adjust to that. The reviewer is not readily available to answer my questions, so I'm improvising somewhat. Instead of Given/When/Then, I could also use Arrange/Act/Assert, I guess. And, lastly: this is a unit test, not integration test.

Comment: @sisyphus: Btw, the mock is not emulating **user** behaviour, but rather emulating fetching via HTTP.

Comment: I think your approach is OK as long as you have a separate test for the first part of this "workflow". But in that case this test should not repeat the assertions of that other test.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Upvoted. Could you write down the benefits of  having this as two separate tests? On the other hand, a cost seems to be some amount of duplication and multiplying the number of tests ~2-fold...